# A question about projective modules.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

Suppose that we have a commutative ring $R$  with an idempotent $e$, and $M$ an $R$-module  such that $Me$ is $Re$-projective. I am interested  to know under which conditions  this implies that $M$ is $R$-projective.

That would be true if $M(1-e)$ is  $R(1-e)$-projective, but as Martin remarked that  is not true.

Any remark will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you allow $e=0$? (Probably not.)

Comment: Yes i mean non trivial idempotents.

Comment: Under *no* condition: Martin's example works here, because you have $R\cong Re\times R(1-e)$ and $M=Me\oplus M(1-e)$ with the action of $R$ on $Me$ being the same as that of $Re$ and similarly for the other summand. So you can take $M(1-e)$ to be a non projective module over $R(1-e)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any product $R_1 \times R_2$, a projective $R_1$-module $M_1$ and a non-projective $R_2$-module $M_2$. Then $M_1 \times M_2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Hello @Martin, i have edited the question.

Comment: I have answered the question, right? $Me$ and $M(1-e)$ have nothing to do with each other. If one is projective or even free or zero, the other module could be still *anything*.

Comment: (central) Idempotent "means" direct product. Yep.

Comment: Yes you answer the question. Sorry but in that moment i was not clear in what i was asking. I actually want some conditions on the ring $R.$